# How to unload an nsmutablearray of strings into a text box

Tags: ios, textbox, nsmutablearray

I have an array of strings that holds a summary of purchases and I need to display that array into a text box whenever that view loads. What would the code look like to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would use `componentsJoinedByString`

```
//arr is your curent array
NSString *str = [arr componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
textField.text = str;
```

Comment: Would this put them on top of each other?
string 1
string 2

versus

string1 string2...etc

Comment: How would I put them on top of each other not next to each other?

Comment: instead of [arr componentsJoinedByString:@" "]; use [arr componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];, this will combine them above each other

Comment: Actually I made a mistake. It was not a text box it was a UILabel. when I use your current code it crashes when I add str to the UILabel.

Comment: I reasked this question so I could add code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285927/program-crashes-when-adding-nsmutablearray-of-strings-to-a-uilabel