# Program crashes when adding NSMutableArray of strings to a UILabel

Tags: ios, string, nsmutablearray, uilabel

When I add this array of strings to the summaryText UILabel it crashes. Please let me know how to fix this.

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

arr = [Singleton getArray];

NSString *str = [arr componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
summaryText.text = str;
```

This is what was brought up when i command clicked summaryText

```
@implementation TotalViewController
@synthesize tax,taxLabel,total,totalLabel,final,finalLabel,fiveLabel,threeLabel,twoLabel,five,three,two, points, pointsLabel,summaryText;
```

Comment: you're also leaking the first reference to `arr`

Comment: For starters, where's the declaration of the UILabel?

Comment: Where and how is `summaryText` defined? Sidenote: it's code like this that gives me nightmares...

Comment: How do i find that? The crash log.

Comment: @JohnnyCox How do you find what?

Comment: @JohnnyCox press on command and click on summaryText, it will take you to the definition of summaryText

Comment: I posted that information above. I added breakpoints in my code and it crashes on the line summaryText.text = str;

Comment: @JohnnyCox Sorry, misunderstanding.  I meant: where are you instantiating it?  Where do you say `summaryText = something;`?

Comment: I'm not. Im using xcode with the interface builder. I thought that was taken care of. I haven't instantiated any of my other labels and they all work fine.

Comment: @JohnnyCox Okay, that makes sense (though it might have been helpful to mention in your original post...).  What error is output to the console when it crashes?

Answer (score 0):

I had suggested `initWithArray`, but not clear why you don't replace entire above snippet with:

```
summaryText.text = [[Singleton getArray] componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

But as others pointed out, your crash isn't here, this just simplifies your code. The problem has to rest elsewhere, probably related to the definition/creation of summaryText. Hard to say without seeing crash log or more code.

**Update:**

You said that you created this control in Interface Builder. You might want to double check your "connections inspector" for that control and make sure your outlet is set up correctly. This sounds a lot like a control that hasn't been set up correctly in Interface Builder. Or you can look at you .h file in Xcode and it will tell you if it's successfully linked to a control in Interface Builder. You'll see a little "circle" to the left of the source code, a solid dot in the circle means that your outlet is hooked up correctly, and empty circle means that it's not (e.g. in this example below, `contactName`, `contactAddress`, and `contactPhone` are all linked up correctly, but `myLabel` is not):

[image: Some sample IBOutlets]

Comment: Please, just no. If you ever find yourself writing that, you've gone wrong. Use `-copy` if you ever want this behaviour instead.

Comment: @jrtc27 lol. quite right. frankly, given this code sample, the whole creation of a new array is just silly if you just wanted `componentsJoinedByString`.

Comment: How do I find the crash log so I can post here?

Comment: @JohnnyCox For crashes the simulator, you just ran the app from Xcode, you'll see the crash log the "debugger area" at the bottom panel in Xcode, in the "console" section on the right panel of that "debugger area". Alternatively, if you run the "console" app on your Mac, you can see it there. If it's crashing on a device, go to the Organizer, click on Devices, and you see the logs there.

Comment: @JohnnyCox Given that you created in Interface Builder, you might want to double check your "connections inspector" for that control and make sure your outlet is set up correctly. This sounds a lot like a control that hasn't been set up correctly in Interface Builder. See my updated answer above.